# how to know whether builtin properties/methods in sequelizejs instance overriden?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am new to [sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html#values-of-an-instance). I am confused by how to list all builtin properties/methods in one sequelizejs instance.

How to know whether some builtin properties/methods are changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are available on the Sequelize `Model` via the `attributes` property.

```
const attrs = Model.attributes;
```

You can determine if an attribute has been changed by using [`Instance.changed(attr)`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-changed) method. Passing the field name will return true if it has been modified.

If you want to look through them all...

```
Models.attributes.forEach((attr) => {
  console.log(attr, instance.changed(attr));
});
```